# Synchronizing Thread and Event

Tags: c#, console, .net-2.0, manualresetevent, event-wait-handle

In my console application, Synchronizing the events within in thread makes difficult.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Example
    {
        private static Button _button;
        private static readonly EventWaitHandle Ewh = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
        private static readonly EventWaitHandle Btn = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);

        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            _button = new Button();
            _button.Click += _button_Click;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 0x4; i++)
            {
                var t = new Thread(ThreadProc);
                t.Start(i);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to release a waiting thread.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Ewh.Set();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void _button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new Random().Next(0x1388));
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            Btn.Set();
        }

        public static void ThreadProc(object data)
        {
            _button.PerformClick();
            Btn.WaitOne();
            Btn.Reset();
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} blocks.", data);
            Ewh.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} exits.", data);
        }
    }
}
```

Application gives result as some random numbers followed by thread blocks and after signaling [EventWaithandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx) data threads are exited printed on console.

aim is to print the data by following manner like

*random data

thread Block

random data

thread Block

....

thread exiting

...*

Sample output

1234

Thread 2 Blocks

2345

Thread 0 Blocks

3456

Thread 1 Blocks

....

Thread 1 exiting

Thread 4 Exiting

....

How to synchronize thread and event inside thread in that manner.

Comment: please post once again how you wish the data to be printed in the Console, I do not quite understand your goal :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code.  It uses the AutoResetEvent for the Btn.  Also, I see that you are creating Button and access it from the background thread.  I removed this code and instead called the ButtonClick method directly.  Here is the resulting code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Example
    {
        private static Button _button;
        private static readonly EventWaitHandle Ewh = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
        private static readonly EventWaitHandle Btn = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            Ewh.Reset();
            _button = new Button();
            _button.Click += _button_Click;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 0x4; i++)
                new Thread(ThreadProc).Start(i);
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to release a waiting thread.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Ewh.Set();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void _button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new Random().Next(0x1388));
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        public static void ThreadProc(object data)
        {
            Btn.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} blocks.", data);
            _button.PerformClick();
            Btn.Set();
            Ewh.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} exits.", data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its Fails please check ,by setting a loop count to 10 or more,synchronized means it have to work all the time with irrespective to thread count.

Comment: I've tried to set it to 10, 100 and it always works perfectly.  Try to copy the code as is and test

Comment: Its fails,i think you've single core processor.run it in some other PC with having more than one processor.

Comment: I see :)  change the Main method as I've changed in the original answer.

Comment: Thank you,to span you're time on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Task Schedulers and Synchronization Context instead. Create a Synchronization Context in the Main thread and pass it to the task that you want to execute in the main thread.

Comment: In .NET 2.0?? I hate to tell you, but I think that does not exist back then.

Comment: Its .Net 4.0 API ,I raised question for .Net 2.0